# Immi account password recovery without answering security questions

Tags: visas, australia

I have forgotten both my immi account (Australian Visa Application Account) password and security questions.

When I tried to recover my password through the option ''*I have forgotten my ImmiAccount username or password*'' in immi accout webpage, I was required to answer my security questions. Regrettably, I have forgotten my answers to these questions.

How can I recover my immi account without answering the security questions?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried filling their [Technical Support Form](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/departmental-forms/online-forms/immiaccount-technical-support-form)

Comment: Yes, I tried. However, in that form, there was an option, ''Unable to access ImmiAccount''. When I selected it, the answer was just referring me to the option ''I have forgotten my ImmiAccount username or password'' in immi accout webpage, which is not useful.

Comment: They do add "For further assistance contact the [Global Service Centre](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/contact-us/telephone) as new passwords cannot be provided via email." so maybe you can follow the links to find a contact number and speak with them

Comment: I tried that option too. However, the information in ''Global Service Centre;; was not really helpful. I think I need to find the wright answers to my security questions as the quickest possible way. Thank you.

Comment: Finding the answers to your security questions is probably the best approach, but the Global Service Centre link provided includes phones numbers which enable you to contact them for alternative means of retrieving access to your account.

Comment: Happy to say, I finally recovered my account. Thank you all.

Comment: @Adel I'm glad that worked out for you. You could be of great service to the community by providing an answer that detailed what you did to recover your account, including some of the things you tried that didn't work. Just imagine your frustration if you'd come here, found someone else had already asked this question, then posted a comment saying "never mind, I fixed it". Please help the next person! (Do not, of course, reveal any personal info in your answer.)

Comment: I landed the same trouble and cannot recollect my secret questions/answers.
Could you please help with the workaround you did to get over this issue.
Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: @Mani The OP (Adel) hasn't been logged in to Stack Exchange since the day they posted the question. It's unlikely they will notice or respond. Make your own question and then when you figure it out, make sure you answer your own question with the procedure you used.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.